# @types/gtag.js error: Argument of type '"config"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"consent"'

Tags: typescript, google-analytics, typescript-typings

I'm trying to add Google Analytics to a Next.js site. I'm following [this](https://mariestarck.com/add-google-analytics-to-your-next-js-application-in-5-easy-steps/) guide which is in JavaScript but my app is TypeScript. After I install @types/gtag.js I am getting this error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"config"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"consent"'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(19, 5): The last overload is declared here.
```

on this line of my code:

```
window.gtag('config', process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS, {
    page_path: url,
})
```

Here are the type definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/gtag.js/index.d.ts

I'm not sure if the types are incorrect but the code presumably works since it's straight from the tutorial.

My temporary workaround is to declare `gtag: any`:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    gtag: any
  }
}
```

Answer (score 26):

I got this error and I fixed this by add type `string` to `NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS` (in your case). In my case it because type of `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS` is `string | undefined`.

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer. Thanks

Comment: How exactly do you add type `string`?

Comment: window &&
    window.gtag &&
    window.gtag('config', process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS as string, {
      page_path: url,
    });